# Canjs view not rendering data

Tags: javascript, ejs, canjs, canjs-view

I'm having a little issue when wanting to render data on one of my ejs views. I send the parameters to the view, but this value is not shown in the view, instead it appears as a blank space.

```
;(function(namespace, undefined) {
'use strict';

var PageHeader = can.Control({
    defaults: {         
    }
}, {
    'init': function(element, options) {
        var self = this;
        $('body').append( can.view('js/views/header.ejs', {data:  'foo'} ) );
    },
    destroy: function() {
        can.Control.prototype.destroy.call(this);
    }
    /*end of events*/
});
namespace.Controllers = namespace.Controllers || {};
namespace.Controllers.PageHeader = PageHeader; }(this));

//testing view header.ejs
 <div>
      <%= this.data %>
  </div>
```

The view is render as a blank space, and the  object is empty.
I'm I missing something, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: it ended up being the version. I changed to an old one and it worked perfectly. Is there something different with the lates version at their site?

Answer (score 0):

As of can `2.0 mustache` is the default view renderer and ejs is supported if you add it to your can build. So if your using `2.0 add EJS` to the can build as well as in your can.view include the file type (i.e.) can.`view('myfile.ejs', data);`

Comment: How to go about if i'm using script tag to have the ejs content ?